# Linux + what is the best approach to run in parallel yum update on hundreds Linux machines

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, redhat, yum

I have around ~700 Linux redhat machines

and I want to run the commands "yum update" on all them

I was thinking about the following approach as described in my script

but I not sure if "yum update &" in my script is the right approach ?

& was added to command in order to run the  command Independently

```
 more list.txt 

 server1
 server2 
 .
 .
```

my script

```
#!/bin/bash
SSH="/usr/bin/ssh -n -o  ConnectTimeout=5 -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -xaq"


for server_name in ` cat list.txt `
do

echo "Run yum update on sevrer - $server_name"

$SSH $server_name "yum -y update &"

sleep 0.1

done
```

I will happy to know other ideas & suggestions about how to run in parallel yum update on 700 machines

Comment: You should use pdsh or pssh for this.

Comment: I done have these commands on my linux machines , so I cant use them

Comment: You just need it on the machine from which you launch the command. No need to install them on every machine. It will perform the loop you are doing under the hood efficiently and take care of stdout/err for you. They are incredible time savers, you should try them.

Comment: yes I know , but I cant to install this command on the machine that run the ssh on all machine because we not allow to add new commands on machine

Comment: Ask for the owner of the machine to give you the right tools to do your job, or download the project source and compile it if needed and add them to your path, or launch a virtual machine / docker instance with the tools available...

Comment: thx - but we prefer to use the current system without to make any changes

Comment: Hint: and what happens if 1% of those calls go wrong? Will your self-baked script notice that?

Comment: while I agree with above comments, I did notice you have a typo in your code. Didn't you mean `$SSH "$server_name" "yum -y update &"` ? And of course as mentioned, you'll need to capture any output and confirm there are no errors. Good luck!

Comment: yes I add the "$" before server_name   , thx

Comment: And just for the record: from a "how I write, proper secure scripts" point of view ... your little bash script there is **miles** away from being reasonable. Dont get me wrong: but that looks very much amateurish to me.

Comment: The ssh command will exit after running the job in the background. However, since the controlling tty no longer exists (ssh has exited), a HUP signal will be sent to all processes in the session, leading to yum getting interrupted (and hence killed) midway. This will happen on all your hosts.

Comment: so do you recommended to add the 1>/dev/null 2>&1 after the "&" ?

Answer (score 6):

Seriously, on that scale, you should use one of the many existing configuration management systems like [chef](https://learn.chef.io/), [puppet](https://docs.puppet.com/), [salt](https://saltstack.com/), ... or an orchestration tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/orchestration), [Fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) ...

If you are really responsible for several **hundred** systems in a way that you have to control there installation levels; then I would call that: *professional* server administration. Or, well, to be precise: I would call that the *responsibility* of a professional admin.

And in 2016, I tend to say: the professional thing is **not** to script something together on your own. Instead, the professional approach would be to learn about existing configuration management systems; decide which one best fits your needs, and introduce that to your server farm. And to then use it for tasks like this.

Comment: This is an orchestration problem and not a configuration management problem though, so he would be looking at Ansible, Fabric, MCollective, etc. Otherwise, this advice is dead on.

Comment: Thanks. I added your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

[Foreman](http://www.theforeman.org) open-source project might be for you, it has Remote Execution plugin that lets you do that. It can also help you mirror the content with Katello plugin and much more.